# RDP redirecting directly to IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, rdp

I've got an RDS setup being worked on at the moment, however now it's all setup I'm trying to RDP to one of the servers, theres the following

- RDS Broker
- RDS01
- RDS02
- Sep DC servers etc

When I try to RDP directly to the IP of one of the RDS servers it's redirecting me to the other RDP server and I can't work out. Doesnt seem to be load balancing etc

Here is a video of it in action:

https://cdn-e1.streamable.com/video/mp4/m6tf.mp4?token=1480455590_30e022803a85bff47211a107ac9f0aaf876e14e2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDS Connection Broker is a load balancer. When you connect to a specific RDS server it queries the RDS Connection Broker, which redirects you to a RDS server in the farm.

Round Robin DNS and NLB are merely ways of distributing the incoming connections, not a way of distributing the user sessions across your RDS servers, that's the job of the RDS Connection Broker, which is working as expected.

Comment: Ah, so what's the expected way to do maintenance on a specific server without messing up the load balancing?

Comment: If you need to connect directly to a specific session host, use the command line and add the /admin flag: "mstsc.exe /admin /v:<sessionhost>".

Answer (score 2):

When you launch the *Remote Desktop Connection* application with the */admin* parameter, you can connect directly into a specific RDS server with an Administrator privileged account.

```
Win + R
mstsc /admin
```